# Make abstraction for scss responsive mixins

Tags: sass

I have a mixin that looks like this:

```
 * Mixin for setting responsive width content values
 */
@mixin screenWidth($default-width: $min-width-sm, $minmax: min) {
  @media screen and (#{$minmax}-width: $default-width) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

I use it as such:

```
@mixin main-header-sm {
  @include screenWidth($min-width-sm) {
    height: $header-height-sm;
  }
}

@mixin zp-main-menu-small-sm {
  @include screenWidth($min-width-sm) {
    position: sticky;
    position:  -webkit-sticky;
    display: block;
  }
}

@mixin zp-main-menu-medium-sm {
  @include screenWidth($min-width-sm) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Which I wrap for example like this:

```
@mixin responsive-main-header {
  @include main-header-sm;
  @include main-header-md;
}
```

Which I finally use like this:

```
  header.main-header {
    @include position(fixed, 0 0 null 0);
    background: $zp-color-green;
    color: white;
    z-index: 999;
    height: $header-height-sm;

    @include responsive-main-header;
  }
```

Is there a way to abstract this repetition:

```
@mixin main-header-sm {
  @include screenWidth($min-width-sm) { /* --> this */
    height: $header-height-sm;
  }
}

@mixin zp-main-menu-small-sm {
  @include screenWidth($min-width-sm) { /* --> this */
    position: sticky;
    position:  -webkit-sticky;
    display: block;
  }
}

@mixin zp-main-menu-medium-sm {
  @include screenWidth($min-width-sm) { /* --> this */
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: By repetition do you mean calling the mixin `screenWidth` or passing the variable `$min-width-sm`?

Comment: I mean that I need to repeat the screenwidth mixin for every other mixin that I wrap it with.